# Actual price of trekking to everest base camp.?

Tags: nepal, trekking, mount-everest

I've been searching a [trip to everest base camp](https://upscaleadventures.com/package/everest-base-camp-trek) and found out this ([Upscale Adventure](https://upscaleadventures.com)) and been talking with them for the trip. We are 5 friends planning for the trek to everest base camp for the next fall.

Although they are offering us price of USD 800 for each person for private group trip and with everything included mentioned in their page. Though they have listed USD 1600 for this package in their page.

My concern is that how much would it cost for if we everything by our self. Like Accomodation, meals, transportation, permits, guides & porter ? And USD 800 is go to deal ?

Comment: Answer from 2017. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100064/cost-difference-of-trekking-solo-vs-with-a-group-to-ebc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cost difference of Trekking solo vs with a group to EBC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100064/cost-difference-of-trekking-solo-vs-with-a-group-to-ebc)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Going through the links you've suggested. I came to conclusion that it's better to go with the company and own group. We save quite a few bucks through this.